# Increment the textview value on button click in listview

Tags: android, android-listview, textview, android-button

I have a `button` and `textview` together in `listview` row. I want to increment the textview value while click the button in the same row. Below is my code, here its updating multiple rows instead of single row,where I need to.

```
package com.example.digitalmenuactivity;

public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter   {

private Activity activity;
private Activity activity1;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;

private int mCounter1=1;
private int counter=1;
private int[] counters;
int pos;





public ListAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    counters = new int[5];
}


static class ViewHolder {

   protected TextView mSwitcher1=null;
    protected Button btnDelete=null;
    protected TextView title=null;
    protected TextView artist=null;
    protected TextView duration=null;
    protected ImageView thumb_image=null;

}



public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
} 



public View getView(final int position,final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    pos = getItemViewType(position);
    if(convertView==null)
    {
      vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);


      viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
      viewHolder.title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title);
      viewHolder.artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.description); 
      viewHolder.duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.price);
      viewHolder.thumb_image =(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); 

    viewHolder.btnDelete = (Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.plus);
    viewHolder.mSwitcher1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.switcher1);




    vi.setTag(viewHolder);

    }
    else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.btnDelete.setTag(pos);
    viewHolder.mSwitcher1.setTag(pos);



    viewHolder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


             pos = (Integer) view.getTag();


            int temp=counters[pos];
            temp++;
            counters[pos]= temp;

            viewHolder.mSwitcher1.setText(String.valueOf(counters[pos]));
            notifyDataSetChanged();

            Log.d("^^^^^^", "button clicked" + counters.length);
            Log.d("^^^^^^", "temp" + temp);

        }

        });
    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
    song = data.get(position);

    viewHolder.title.setText(song.get(FoodActivity.KEY_TITLE));
    viewHolder.artist.setText(song.get(FoodActivity.KEY_ARTIST));
    viewHolder.duration.setText(song.get(FoodActivity.KEY_DURATION));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(FoodActivity.KEY_THUMB_URL),viewHolder.thumb_image);
    return vi;
}
```

}

Comment: Hey guyzz. . issue got solved. .thanks for your support. The problem was with this line : notifyDataSetChanged() . I commented this line and its working fine now. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are doing short of mistakes: listed below:

**First**

Used:

> viewHolder.mSwitcher1.setTag(position);

Instead:

> viewHolder.mSwitcher1.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));

**Second**

No need to get view *tag* twice, once is enough to get exact selected position,adapter code will be look like below:

ListviewAdapter:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<String> getData = new ArrayList<String>();
    Context c;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    int pos;
    int boxState[];
    SharedPreferences prefs;

    private int mCounter1 = 1;
    private int counter = 1;
    private int[] counters;

    public ListviewAdapter(Context cont, ArrayList<String> data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        c = cont;
        getData = data;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(cont);

        counters = new int[5];

    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getData.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        private TextView name = null;
        private Button button = null;

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getData.size();
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final ViewHolder holder;
        View vi = convertView;
        pos = getItemViewType(position);

        if (convertView == null) {

            vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            holder.button = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

            vi.setTag(holder);
        }

        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }

        holder.button.setTag(pos);
        holder.name.setTag(pos);

        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                pos = (Integer) v.getTag();

                int temp = counters[pos];
                temp++;
                counters[pos] = temp;

                notifyDataSetChanged();
                holder.name.setText(String.valueOf(counters[pos]));

                Log.d("^^^^^^", "button clicked" + counters.length);
                Log.d("^^^^^^", "temp" + temp);

            }
        });

        return vi;
    }

}
```

Comment: i'm not getting any error,but updated textview values reflecting on multiple rows

Comment: what you modified? I told you to change this line   viewHolder.mSwitcher1.setText(String.valueOf(counters[pos])); of code but you didn't check my code properly.

Comment: download and check this demo.http://www.nippyzip.com/uploads/130410040813-93882.zip

Comment: Hey,issue got solved. .thanks for your support. The problem was with this line : notifyDataSetChanged() . I commented this line and its working fine now. :-)

Answer (score 1):

And you are incorrectly using ViewHolder pattern. Read this:

http://www.jmanzano.es/blog/?p=166

Comment: followed the link and modified the code,still the same. .formated code is updated on my question

Comment: Yes, it was not solution to your problem. I think that you should have addidional array with size equal to the number of your textviews where you want to increment values. In this array you should keep values that will be displayed in textviews. And when you want to increment value in one of textviews then you increment an element of the array.

Comment: Hey, issue got solved. .thanks for your support. The problem was with this line : notifyDataSetChanged() . I commented this line and its working fine now. :-)